# Nesting of ajax call function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax function ( with nesting )

```
function open_appointment(id)
{
save_method = 'open_appointment';
$('#form_open_appointment')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
$('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

//Ajax Load data from ajax
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('ReceptionistController/ajax_edit_appointment')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('DoctorController/ajax_edit_patient')?>/" +data.ap_patient, 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('[name="pt_name"]').val(data.pt_name);

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });

        $('#modal_open_appointment').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Open Appointment'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});
 }
```

i want to use  one ajax call into another . i have written the above code but its not working (when nested ), and give show "Failed" . There is problem in nesting of ajax call function

Comment: what does `alert(errorThrown)` give you?

Comment: You don't need 2 ajax calls, if it is all on the same server you can do both at once. And the error function returns useful information: What are the values of the 3 parameters you receive back? You can also see in the developer tools what the exact response is.

Comment: I think has some error in the second call..print the full error in console

Comment: i am getting    value in " data.ap_patient" from first ajax call which need to be used in the second ajax  call  .. how can i do both at once  jeroen

Comment: if you run your nested ajax alone, will it produce issue?

Comment: @kashif   add "@" before his name, to let him know in his messages box that you commented on his comment

Comment: replace `alert('Failed');` with `alert(errorThrown)` to know what type of error has occurred in the request

Comment: ok @ Accountant م  alert(errorThrown) gives "Not Found" .

Comment: @kashif Great, now check this request in your browser network activity, is the request `Path` is what you expect ?

Comment: ok my Bad , @Accountant م thank . I got it .  thank you :) . i have called the wrong Controller here

Comment: Promises is the best way to achieve this. Other way you can just set a local variable on the success and than check it after to make the second request.

Answer (score 3):

You could use promises like below

Code is untested...

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
var getAppointment = function() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('ReceptionistController/ajax_edit_appointment')?>/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                reject('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });

    })
}

var editPatient = function(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('DoctorController/ajax_edit_patient')?>/" +data.ap_patient, 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
                resolve(data);

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                reject('Failed');
            }
        });
    }
}

getAppointment()
    .then(function(data) {
        return editPatient(data)
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        $('[name="pt_name"]').val(data.pt_name);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is looking good,but first, check the outer ajax request that it's working correctly and return the data.ap_patient correctly or not. after that call inner ajax request. and also check  inspect elements that request is going to correct action methods or not.

Comment: both ajax separately are working ( they work well with static parameter ) . but nesting  one with other create the trouble

Comment: first don't write inner ajax request. check the outer one it's working or not?? if it's work then write inner request?? if outer not worked . may be your Controller not exists.

Comment: 1) when used the outer ajax call it  return the expected value , when using the inner ajax (separate  with constant parameter in url ) also give the expected result . but nesting the inner with outer ajax call is not working

Comment: Now see in inspect elements that next request going or not?? may be it's not going to action method.